# Looping through 2 elements at a time

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to create error messages for labels on a form. Problem is that it's not working. The submitted input must be a number. Whenever it is not, clicking on the button should return a error message on the specific label.

Problem is - it only works OK if the first thing you submit is a correct set of numbers. I can't seem to get the combinations right. Do you know how I can solve this?

```js
let coordValues = document.getElementsByClassName("input-card__input");
let submitBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("input-card__button");
let inputLabel = document.getElementsByClassName("input-card__label");

let weatherArray = [];
let labelArray = [];

for(let j=0;j<inputLabel.length;j++) {
  labelArray.push(inputLabel[j].innerHTML);
}

submitBtn[0].addEventListener("click", function checkInputs() {
  for(let i = 0; i<coordValues.length;i++) {
    for(let k = 0; k<inputLabel.length;k++) {
    if(coordValues[i].value === "" || isNaN(Number(coordValues[i].value))) {
      inputLabel[k].classList.add("input-card__label--error");
      inputLabel[k].innerHTML = "Oops! Write a number here."
      console.log("nop");
      break;
    } else {
      inputLabel[k].classList.remove("input-card__label--error");
      inputLabel[k].innerHTML = labelArray[k];
      console.log("yep");
      break;
    }
  }
}
});
```

```css
.input-card__label--error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input-card">
        <h1 class="input-card__title">Where are you?</h1>
        <h3 class="input-card__label">LONGITUDE</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Longitude" class="input-card__input">
        <h3 class="input-card__label">ALTITUDE</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Altitude" class="input-card__input">
        <button class="input-card__button">Show me weather ⛅</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Need to prevent the form from submitting if error encountered. [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 2):

There's a few errors in your code, here's a version I modified:

```
submitBtn[0].addEventListener("click", function checkInputs() {
  for(let i = 0; i<coordValues.length;i++) {
    if(coordValues[i].value === "" || isNaN(Number(coordValues[i].value))) {
      inputLabel[i].classList.add("input-card__label--error");
      inputLabel[i].innerHTML = "Oops! Write a number here."
      console.log("nop");
      return;
    }
    inputLabel[i].classList.remove("input-card__label--error");
    inputLabel[i].innerHTML = labelArray[i];
  }

  console.log("yep");  
});
```

One issue is the double for loop, it over complicates what you're trying to do.
Then once removed your code is left with a for loop then a test which all end up with a break so you never do more than one iteration.

The code above basically says log yes unless you find a reason to log nop.

Comment: thank you! but in the case of leaving all fields empty and clicking the button, why does only the first label get changed to the error msg? I want to make both of them change to error msg.

Answer (score 1):

In this case we need a flag to remember the error state:

```
submitBtn[0].addEventListener("click", function checkInputs() {
  let allInputValid = true
  for(let i = 0; i<coordValues.length;i++) {
    if(coordValues[i].value === "" || isNaN(Number(coordValues[i].value))) {
      inputLabel[i].classList.add("input-card__label--error");
      inputLabel[i].innerHTML = "Oops! Write a number here."
      console.log("nop");
      allInputValid = false
    }
    else {
      inputLabel[i].classList.remove("input-card__label--error");
      inputLabel[i].innerHTML = labelArray[i];
    }
  }

  if ( allInputValid )
    console.log("yep");  
});
```

Whenever an error is spotted, allInputValid is set to false. If there's two errors you set allInputValid to false twice.